# WebSphere OpenJPA performance issue

Tags: jpa, websphere, openjpa

I am facing performance issues with one of my JPA queries. I am using WebSphere 8.5.5 and the JPA implementation provided with it. While debugging the issue I could see the following trace log

```
[2/15/16 15:48:20:534 SGT] 000000f6 Query         3   openjpa.Query: Trace: Executing query: Query: org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl@96998a13; candidate class: 
[2/15/16 15:48:20:535 SGT] 000000f6 DataCache     3   openjpa.DataCache: Trace: Cache miss while looking up key "org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryKey@b50e0a74
[2/15/16 15:48:20:538 SGT] 000000f6 jdbc_SQLDiag  3   openjpa.jdbc.SQLDiag:  Trace: Eager relations: 
[2/15/16 15:48:20:540 SGT] 000000f6 jdbc_SQL      3   openjpa.jdbc.SQL: Trace: <t 1677979087, conn -1051179210> executing prepstmnt 1704630525 
[2/15/16 15:48:22:576 SGT] 000000f6 jdbc_SQL      3   openjpa.jdbc.SQL: Trace: <t 1677979087, conn -1051179210> [2036 ms] spent
[2/15/16 15:48:52:505 SGT] 000000f6 DataCache     3   openjpa.DataCache: Trace: Put key "org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryKey@b50e0a74
[2/15/16 15:48:52:506 SGT] 000000f6 jdbc_JDBC     3   openjpa.jdbc.JDBC: Trace: <t 1677979087, conn -1051179210> [0 ms] close
```

Now if you carefully notice the query execution takes around 2 seconds, which is acceptable, but there is a 30 seconds gap between jdbc execution and next log statement. That is some query cache put. Can anyone explain where this 30 seconds are spent?

Comment: you mean "can anyone guess what was going on on my machine during this 30 second period without any information of what was running?"

Comment: @NeilStockton There was nothing else going on on my machine. My guess is that this is the data transfer time between db machine (that is remote) and  app server (that is my local). As I am not using pagination on this query due to some odd constraints, this particular scenario fetches a good amount of data. But it will need debugging the openJPA code to ascertain that.

Comment: @dkaustubh Neil is saying there is no way for anyone to guess what might be going wrong.  Can you see from database logs that a query at that time is taking 30s?  You could try enabling some additional trace (RRA=all), which might give a hint about which SQL statements are being executed to see whether that's the cause of the slowness.  If neither of those give results, it might be best to open a PMR with IBM.